# mysql foreign keys and indexs

Tags: mysql, innodb

if i have 2 tables

```
user
-----------------
id integer PK
name varchar

address
----------------
id integer PK
user_id integer
city varchar
```

Now, if exists an one to many foreign key between user.id <-> adress.user_id
it is required also to create an index in the user_id column for speed up select queries?

Or because I have created a foreign key I have also implicitly created an index that will used from the dmbs for speed up queries?

Comment: As the foreign key is specified, it is implicit you have an index for that column

Comment: could you point me to some official reference about this?

Comment: Official like the MySQL documentation on foreign keys, where a quick page search on 'index' tells all? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Some particular reason for having a 1:1 relationship?  Usually (not always) it is better to have one table instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is [created automatically when creating an FK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> The index_name value is ignored if there is already an explicitly
>   defined index on the child table that can support the foreign key.
>   Otherwise, **MySQL implicitly creates a foreign key index** that is named
>   according to the following rules ...

Answer (score 0):

See this arcticle : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, **there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed** as the first columns in the
>   same order.

So there is an index on that table